# Self conscious when pronouncing "R's"

Tags: pronunciation

I remember taking special reading classes in 5th and 6th grade for this, but basically I have trouble pronouncing words that use the letter 'r'. I don't really know why this is as I am fine with all the other letters. But whenever I say a word that has a strong 'R' to it, like 'Rural', it's extremely hard to pronounce. I think this isn't normal because my family and friends never heard of this issue, and I have looked online but with no luck.

Also, for some odd reason when I do pronounce these words my mind adds emphasis to the 'R' sounding, and I feel like I am really screwing up the pronunciation. I don't know how else to explain it. But I feel like if I subconsciously talk without thinking (or talk really fast) I don't even notice the 'R' sound.

My problem is, since my brain does add that emphasis, it has a negative affect on me. It makes me feel like I am mispronouncing the letter/word and just doesn't feel right.

I'm wondering if there is anything I can do as an adult now to help with this? It doesn't happen when reading, only when speaking out loud.

Comment: I think this is an area where meeting in person with a speech therapist is likely to be much more useful to you than reading posts from strangers online.

Comment: Anyway, here are some other questions about pronouncing r: [The american R sound](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/210002), [The pronunciation of the letter r in British English](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/316813), [Exercises for pronouncing the r](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/169401), [How to pronounce the letter /r/](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/267928), [Is an American “r” sound retroflexed or retracted?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/221473), [Pronunciation of “r”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13984)

Comment: You have lots of company! Do the following articles describe your problem?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhotacism and http://www.wikihow.com/Pronounce-R's  I found these articles and others by googling "can't pronounce r"

Comment: [Technique of pronouncing the rhotic “r”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/293516), [How do I pronounce “wrong” correctly instead of “long”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/89797)

Comment: I would suggest that you have a few sessions with a speech therapist.  The therapist will be able to accurately evaluate your current speech, recognize any problems, and give you advice in the way of exercises or whatever to correct any problems.

Comment: Oh wow, thanks for the links! I had no idea this was a thing, that actually makes me feel much better.

Comment: @sumelic I am watching her video now and the tongue curling trick actually helps a lot.  Thank you guys so much.

Answer (score 1):

*Is there a way to treat Rhotacism in adults aged 20+?*

Learn how to position your tongue to pronounce a clear 'R' sound.

> So, after wading through some useless info on short palates, I learned the word "rhotacism," and then took the hop skip and jump internet links to Youtube, where I often end up it seems. And so, **literally 20 minutes** of Youtube videos taught me how to position my tongue and pronounce a clear R sound! [*exclamation!*] –[quora.com](https://www.quora.com/Is-there-a-way-to-treat-Rhotacism-in-adults-aged-20+)